# Unity Open/Close doors with bool paramaters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and i'm creating some project. I've already made open and close animation, disabled loop time, created bool parameter "open" and put conditions:

```
Empty -> openDoor (open = true)
openDoor -> closeDoor (open = false)
closeDoor -> openDoor (open = true)
```

With left click i have to open and close the door. This is the C# code, I tried playing with if states but I can't get it work. Any help?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        anim.SetBool("open", true);

        if (anim.GetBool("open") == true)
        {
            anim.SetBool("open", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You set "open" to true. Immediatly after you check if "open" is true. Of course it is, because you just set it to true, remember? So, because you have set "open" to "true", the `if` statement says "_Yup!. Sure 'open' is true_" and your code proceeds to immediately set "open" to false. All this happens within a fraction of a millisecond, with the practical result of this rather quick tennis match being that "open" is being set (or maintained as) "false"...

Comment: Oh, i see. Well to be honest i was trying to get it work. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to change door status by clicking, you can negate(`not`) the bool like this:

```
void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
   {
      anim.SetBool("open", !(anim.GetBool("open")));

   }
}
```

and if you need to close/open door by clicking on it you can use `OnMouseDown` method:

```
 void OnMouseDown(){
  anim.SetBool("open", !(anim.GetBool("open")));
 }
```

Comment: "_you can `not`_" I guess it is less mind-bending to say "you can negate". Of course you can `not`. There are rarely situations where you can not `not`. See what i mean? Just my opinion of course. And also `not` meant to critizise your answer ;-)

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi Now there is this problem: when I click anywhere on the screen, the door opens. This is a problem with collider or should I add onMouse function?

Comment: i updated answer anther way is to use raycast look here :https://answers.unity.com/questions/332085/how-do-you-make-an-object-respond-to-a-click-in-c.html